# Appending to text file failed in Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, fileoutputstream

I am trying to create a simple text file, and I am successful in doing that by the following code:

```
                file=new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), generateFileName());
                fop=new FileOutputStream(file);
                timeString="Method executed in:"+formatTime(executionTime)+"secs";
                contentInBytes=timeString.getBytes();
                startString="start()".getBytes();
                stopString="stop()".getBytes();
                fop.write(startString);
                fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
                fop.write(contentInBytes);
                fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
                fop.write(stopString);
                fop.flush();
                fop.close();

                Log.d("write","Done writing.");
```

When I try to append same text to it again, the old text gets cleared out resulting in an empty text file.

This is how I tried to append the text:

```
        fOutA=new FileOutputStream(file);  //I also tried: new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
        fOutA = mContext.openFileOutput(textFileName, mContext.MODE_APPEND);
        timeString="Method executed in:"+formatTime(executionTime)+"secs";
        contentInBytes=timeString.getBytes();
        startString="start()".getBytes();
        stopString="stop()".getBytes();
        fOutA.write(startString);
        fOutA.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fOutA.write(contentInBytes);
        fOutA.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fOutA.write(stopString);
        fOutA.flush();
        fOutA.close();
        Log.d("append","Done appending.");
```

The `textfileName` param in the append code-block is same as the `generatedFileName()` in write code-block.

Can someone tell me why it is happening ?

Answer (score 2):

To write to file and append create instance of `FileOutPutStream` and `OutPutStreamWriter` and then use `append` method of `OutputStreamWriter` to append data to the file.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut,true);
myOutWriter.append()
```

Second argument means if text should be appended to the existing file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the suggestion given by Rahil2952, I need to get rid of this line:

```
  fOutA = mContext.openFileOutput(textFileName, mContext.MODE_APPEND);
```

I do not need the `oneFileOutput` and set its mode to `MODE_APPEND`. The `FileOutputStream` itself appends to the existing file when `append` is set to `true` .

Also I do not need to use `OutputStreamWriter`.